# Find Character & Make Capitlise in Javascript

Tags: javascript, find

I've a email as string (let's say "testdrive@gmail.com") and I want to check if email contains character "test" then capitalize that 
(ex. testdrive@gmail.com = **"TESTdrive@gmail.com"**, drivetest@gmail.com= **"driveTEST@gmail.com"**...).

How do I get this in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`String.prototype.toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) functions like this:

```
var original = "testdrive@gmail.com"
var replaceTerm = 'test';
var modified = original.replace(replaceTerm, replaceTerm.toUpperCase());

console.log(modified); //logs TESTdrive@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's `replace` method is the easiest way to find and replace an exact keyword.  The first parameter is the string you are searching for.  The second is what you want to replace that string with.

```
var str = "testdrive@gmail.com";
var x = str.replace('test', 'TEST');
console.log(x); //TESTdrive@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function capitalizer() {
    var mail = "drivetest@gmail.com"; 
    var srchStr = "test";
    var n = mail.search(srchStr);
    var capitalized = mail.replace(srchStr,mail.substr(n, srchStr.length).toUpperCase());
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = capitalized;
}
```